# How correctly import database of phpBB3.0.9

Tags: mysql, import, phpbb3

I need to move my phpBB3 into another server. When I tried to export and import all the information in the fields with varchar type were converted into digits. After searching google found out that it happens because phpBB3 uses utf8_bin collation in all tables, so once you import into utf8_bin it automatically converting into binary code. But I don't want my information to store in this way, neither I want to use utf8_general collation.

How can I import correctly database of my phpBB3 into another server?

Answer (score 1):

Use implemented phpBB database baackup

Comment: Where is that? Because I had searched for it and could not find it.

Comment: Administration -> Maintenance -> Backup. Execuse me for late response